# How to read sql query from xml using java

Tags: java

How to read sql query from xml using java

Comment: You'll need to give more information if you want people to help you

Comment: Give more specific details, probably your xml format and the java code which you have done so far helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML parser. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sql queries already in xml file and trying to read them, you can use any SAX/DOM parser. PS: you may want to enclose the sql queries in XML file in a `CDATA`